# videojs with live stream ts

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get a live stream from an IPTV service into a webpage for a magicmirror project. I am trying to get a single new channel to embed into the page.

I found that the ts file is using this URL, it loads fine in VLC: http://host.net:826/live/hello/413.ts

I created an m3u8 that looks like this:

```
#EXTM3U

#EXTINF:-1

http://host.net:826/live/hello/413.ts
```

When I use this code, the file never loads the stream from the provider.

```
<video-js id="my_video_1" class="center" controls autoplay preload="auto" width="950" height="600">
  <source src="playlist.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
</video-js>
  </div>
<script>
  var player = videojs('my_video_1', {
    html5: {
      hls: {
        overrideNative: true
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

I have run the stream through ffmpeg so that it dumps the files locally and then creates a local m3u8 file. If I then point the above code to that m3u8 file, it loads and runs fine - but I am not live, it's starting to copy the stream local from whenever I start it. So if I refresh the page, the stream begins from the beginning of the locally saved files again.

Answer (score 2):

I know its been 6 months since this questions was asked, I recently worked on the similar issues and figured I'll share my solution.

You can do this with hls.js without creating m3u8 index.

Learn more about hls.js at: https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/

Start by renaming .ts stream URL to .m3u8, there is no need to create m3u8 index http://host.net:826/live/hello/413.ts - >  **http://host.net:826/live/hello/413.m3u8**

HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest"></script>

<button type="button" onclick="PlayVideo();">Play</button>
<video id="video" controls autoplay crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

Javascript:

```
function PlayVideo() {
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    var videoSrc = "http://host.net:826/live/hello/413.m3u8";
    if (Hls.isSupported()) {
        // The following hlsjsConfig is required for live-stream
        var hlsjsConfig = {
            "maxBufferSize": 0,
            "maxBufferLength": 30,
            "liveSyncDuration": 30,
            "liveMaxLatencyDuration": Infinity
        }
        var hls = new Hls(hlsjsConfig);
        hls.loadSource(videoSrc);
        hls.attachMedia(video);
        hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function () {
            video.play();
        });
    } 
    else if (elementId.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')) {
        elementId.src = videoSrc;
        elementId.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function () {
            elementId.play();
        });
    }
}
```

You can further optimize the buffer to what you need it to be by changing values of the hlsjsConfig. See hls.js API details here: https://github.com/dailymotion/hls.js/blob/master/docs/API.md#second-step-instantiate-hls-object-and-bind-it-to-video-element

Comment: The server might throw 404 due you are trying to download a non existing .m3u8 resource...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mpegts.js](https://xqq.im/mpegts.js/) to play this stream.

```
<script src="mpegts.js"></script>
<video id="videoElement"></video>
<script>
     if (mpegts.getFeatureList().mseLivePlayback) {
         var videoElement = document.getElementById('videoElement');
         var player = mpegts.createPlayer({
             type: 'mse', // could also be mpegts, m2ts, flv
             isLive: true,
             url: 'http://example.com/live/livestream.ts'
         });
         player.attachMediaElement(videoElement);
         player.load();
         player.play();
     }
</script>
```

[This link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/videojs-mpegtsjs) below has a plugin for videojs. I hope it helps.